# Is there a way to use SLDS and CSS for different sections of a VF Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am making a VF Page in which I need to use SLDS in some places and CSS in others. The problem is that CSS and SLDS both interfere with each other and the UI gets really weird. Can I define a scope where only CSS is used and a scope where only SLDS is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. In order to do this, you must override the default behavior and create a "scoped" area manually. This isn't clearly outlined in the documentation, but it goes like this:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">

    <head>
        <apex:slds /> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slds-scope">
        <!-- Your SLDS-styled content -->
            <button class="slds-button">
                SLDS Hello
            </button>
        </div>
            <button class="slds-button">
                Unstyled Hello
            </button>
    </body>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.
However, if you are already using your own CSS, you can create a class that in effect "nulls-out" whichever SLDS classes are interfering with you. Then just add that class where you need it and you're good to go.
Maybe a few classes, for different aspects of UI weirdness.